Resolving TPH Inheritance and Migration Issues in Entity Framework Core with Multi-Project Architecture
I’m working on a multi-project architecture with models and data access layers in separate .csproj files (These are Class Libraries.) Using EF Core 8 and TPH inheritance, I encounter the following error when running Add-Migration in VS2022:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'ContentDbContext'. The exception 'The collection navigation 'Paragraphs' cannot be added to the entity type 'Summary' because its CLR type 'ICollection' does not implement 'IEnumerable'. Collection navigations must implement IEnumerable<> of the related entity.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time.

This seems related to my TPH configuration. Below is an outline of the code setup.
Relevant Code
Model Interfaces
public interface IParagraph
{
    string Content { get; set; }
}

public interface IHasParagraphs<T> where T : IParagraph
{
    ICollection<T> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}

Abstract Base Class
public abstract class ParagraphBase : TopicStructureBase, IOrderable, IParagraph
{
    public enum ParagraphParentType { ParagraphBlock, Summary }
    public ParagraphParentType? ParentType { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

Derived Classes
public class SummaryParagraph : ParagraphBase
{
    public Guid SummaryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Summary Summary { get; set; } = new();
}

public class ContentParagraph : ParagraphBase
{
    public Guid ParagraphBlockId { get; set; }
    public virtual ParagraphBlock Block { get; set; } = new();
}

Aggregates
public class Summary : IdentifiableEntityBase, IHasParagraphs<SummaryParagraph>
{
    public virtual ICollection<SummaryParagraph> Paragraphs { get; set; } = new HashSet<SummaryParagraph>();
}

public class ParagraphBlock : TopicElementBase, IHasParagraphs<ContentParagraph>
{
    public virtual ICollection<ContentParagraph> Paragraphs { get; set; } = new HashSet<ContentParagraph>();
}

Entity Configuration
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ParagraphBase> builder)
{
    builder.HasDiscriminator(p => p.ParentType)
           .HasValue<ContentParagraph>(ParagraphParentType.ParagraphBlock)
           .HasValue<SummaryParagraph>(ParagraphParentType.Summary);

    builder.HasOne<Summary>()
           .WithMany(s => s.Paragraphs)
           .HasForeignKey(sp => ((SummaryParagraph)sp).SummaryId);

    builder.HasOne<ParagraphBlock>()
           .WithMany(pb => pb.Paragraphs)
           .HasForeignKey(cp => ((ContentParagraph)cp).ParagraphBlockId);
}

What I’ve Tried

Moving foreign key properties (SummaryId, ParagraphBlockId) and navigation properties into the base class. This resolves the error but breaks specialization, as it forces all derived classes to share these properties.

What I Need Help With

Foreign Key Properties: The logic suggests that ParagraphBase should not be aware of the relationships. Only the derived classes (SummaryParagraph and ContentParagraph) should know about their respective containers (i.e., Summary and ParagraphBlock). These derived classes should have the specialized collections (ICollection<SummaryParagraph> and ICollection<ContentParagraph>). However, EF Core seems to require that the base class be aware of the relationships, which conflicts with this intended design. Shouldn't the relationships be managed by the derived classes instead? If EF Core insists on the base class knowing about the relationships, why is this the case?


Here’s a previous version of the code that worked without issues:
Relevant Code
Model Interfaces
public interface IParent
{
    Guid ParentId { get; set; }
}

public interface IAlineasContainer<T> where T : IAlinea
{
    ICollection<T> Alineas { get; set; }
}

public interface IAlinea
{
    string Content { get; set; }
    Guid? ReplacedById { get; set; }
    Guid? ReplacesId { get; set; }
}

Abstract Base Class
public abstract class AlineaBase : TopicBase, IUtoYearDisplay, IOrderedDisplay, IAlinea
{
    public enum AlineaParentType
    {
        Paragraph,
        Summary
    }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Guid? ReplacedById { get; set; }
    public virtual AlineaBase? ReplacedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid? ReplacesId { get; set; }
    public virtual AlineaBase? Replaces { get; set; }
    public int? DisplayEndYearUto { get; set; }
    public int? DisplayStartYearUto { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public AlineaParentType ParentType { get; set; }
    public virtual object Parent { get; set; }
}

Derived Classes
public class ParagraphAlinea : AlineaBase
{
    public Guid ParagraphId { get; set; }
    public virtual Paragraph Parent { get; set; }
}

public class SummaryAlinea : AlineaBase
{
    public Guid SummaryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Summary Parent { get; set; }
}

Aggregates
public class Paragraph : IllustratedTopicSubdivisionBase, IAlineasContainer<ParagraphAlinea>, IDraftable
{
    public bool IsDraft { get; set; } = true;
    public virtual Article Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ParagraphAlinea> Alineas { get; set; }
}

public class Summary : IdentifierModelBase, IAlineasContainer<SummaryAlinea>, IParent, IDraftable, IIllustratable
{
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDraft { get; set; } = true;
    public virtual Topic Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SummaryAlinea> Alineas { get; set; }
    public Guid? IllustrationAssociationId { get; set; }
    public virtual IllustrationAssociation? Illustration { get; set; }
}

Entity Configuration
private void ConfigureEntities(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Other code
    ConfigureAlineaTablePerHierarchy(modelBuilder);
    ConfigureZeroOrOneToManyRelationships(modelBuilder);
    ConfigureOneToOneRelationships(modelBuilder);
}

private void ConfigureAlineaTablePerHierarchy(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AlineaBase>()
        .HasDiscriminator(x => x.ParentType)
        .HasValue<SummaryAlinea>(AlineaParentType.Summary)
        .HasValue<ParagraphAlinea>(AlineaParentType.Paragraph);
    modelBuilder.Entity<SummaryAlinea>()
        .Property(sa => sa.SummaryId)
        .HasColumnName("SummaryId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ParagraphAlinea>()
        .Property(pa => pa.ParagraphId)
        .HasColumnName("ParagraphId");
}

private void ConfigureZeroOrOneToManyRelationships(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // other code 
    ConfigureZeroOrOneToMany<Summary, SummaryAlinea>(modelBuilder, a => a.Parent, s => s.Alineas, a => a.SummaryId);
    ConfigureZeroOrOneToMany<Paragraph, ParagraphAlinea>(modelBuilder, a => a.Parent, p => p.Alineas, a => a.ParagraphId);
    
    void ConfigureZeroOrOneToMany<TParent, TChild>(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Expression<Func<TChild, TParent>> parentProperty, Expression<Func<TParent, IEnumerable<TChild>>> childrenProperty, Expression<Func<TChild, object>> foreignKeyProperty, DeleteBehavior deleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
        where TParent : class
        where TChild : class
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TChild>()
            .HasOne(parentProperty)
            .WithMany(childrenProperty)
            .HasForeignKey(foreignKeyProperty)
            .OnDelete(deleteBehavior);
    }
}

The entity names were changed, yet this iteration remained operational.

Renaming between the old and new version:



Old Version
New Version




IAlinea
IParagraph


IAlineasContainer<T>
IHasParagraphs<T>


AlineaBase
ParagraphBase


ParagraphAlinea
SummaryParagraph


SummaryAlinea
ContentParagraph


Paragraph
ParagraphBlock


Summary
Summary


Alineas (in Paragraph and Summary)
Paragraphs (in ParagraphBlock and Summary)


AlineaParentType
ParagraphParentType




EF Core does not insist configuring the relationships at base level. Your base entity configuration code does that (and even wrongly by not pairing the navigation properties correctly). Base and derived entities must be configured separately, as in your previous "working" code. Also (unrelated) but never initialize reference navigation properties with = new... - this will cause unexpected behavior at runtime. If you are trying to avoid NRT warnings, that's not the way.

Thank You.
I've changed my code to have 3 config classes, one for the base witch set the TPH, and one for each concret class.
What do you mean : "and even wrongly by not pairing the navigation properties correctly" ?
I also use the "#pragma warning disable CS8618" &"#pragma warning restore CS8618" around the navigation props.

(1) Re: nav props pairing: According to your model, .HasOne<Summary>() must be .HasOne(e => e.Summary). Similar for the other derived entity. In other words, if you have nav property, you have to specify it in {Has|With}{One|Many} methods, otherwise EF will assume 2 (two) separate relationships instead of the intended one. (2) Good that you suppress warnings this way, but still the code is initializing the ref nav props with new (e.g. public virtual Summary Summary { get; set; } = new(); etc.) which you shouldn't. Collections - always, References - never.

I've solved the issue with your help. Thx.
This is what I Should code :
internal class ParagraphBaseConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ParagraphBase>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ParagraphBase> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Paragraph");

        builder
            .HasDiscriminator(p => p.ParentType)
            .HasValue<SummaryParagraph>(ParagraphBase.ParagraphParentType.ParagraphBlock)
            .HasValue<SummaryParagraph>(ParagraphBase.ParagraphParentType.Summary);
    }
}

internal class SummaryParagraphConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SummaryParagraph>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SummaryParagraph> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Paragraph");
      
        builder
            .HasOne<Summary>()
            .WithMany(s => s.Paragraphs)
            .HasForeignKey(sp => sp.SummaryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder
            .Property(p => p.SummaryId)
            .HasColumnName("SummaryId");
    }
}

internal class ContentParagraphConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ContentParagraph>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ContentParagraph> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Paragraph");

        builder
            .HasOne<ParagraphBlock>()
            .WithMany(pb => pb.Paragraphs)
            .HasForeignKey(cp => cp.ParagraphBlockId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder
            .Property(p => p.ParagraphBlockId)
            .HasColumnName("ParagraphBlockId");
    }
}


